# Cannot find file on trying to deploy to heroku (works locally)

Tags: reactjs, heroku, deployment, module

I am trying to deploy my app to Heroku, it works in local but no luck online. I deleted and reinstalled node modules.

I had another error quite related to this (file not found same names etc) I changed the relative paths thinking that would fix the issue but I am getting nothing to come out of it

The error is:

Cannot find file './Components/SearchBar/SearchBar'

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import SearchBar from './Components/SearchBar/SearchBar'
import BusinessList from './Components/BusinessList/BusinessList'
import Business from './Components/Business/Business'
import Yelp from './Components/Util/Yelp'
```

I expected to not pull an error for something so simple, I've poured over the file and folder names and it just is not making sense.

PS I think it's probably unconnected I have const yelpApiKey=process.env.yelpApiKey for my heroku to connect to my API key (typed inside my account)

[image: FILESTRUCTURE]

Comment: What is your build config? If application source is pointing to 'src' folder, you should prevent importing from outside 'src' folder.

Comment: Okay - I am super ignorant of build configs in react, where do I look? 

For some background, I used create react app
npm run build brings me to the same error.

Comment: Can you try removing 'src' from imports. And what is the location of the current file where you are importing?

Comment: I added the file structure as a screenshot

Comment: should it look like 

import Business from './Components/Business/Business.js' 

or 

import SearchBar from './Components/SearchBar/SearchBar.js'

because i got a similar error when it was like that and that's when I changed the file path to try and reflect that the root was there.

Comment: Removing 'src' and '.js' from imports should work. Did you try that? like: import SearchBar from './Components/SearchBar/SearchBar'

Comment: remote: ./src/App.js
remote: Cannot find file './Components/SearchBar/SearchBar' in './src'.

Comment: I am spinning with this because it just doesn't seem to get past that error...and I've tried moving the heirachy of files

Comment: Can you remove all of your business/private code and upload it to github/stackblitz/codesandbox?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/github/Anthematics/BigEats -> its a personal project , go to utils/yelp and paste an api key to run it (yelp api)

Comment: okay so , on my actual github all my folders are in lower case but locally they're not ? wouldn't that cause problems right there ? also sending it to github doesn't change it.

Comment: Ohh.. Can you check in the deployment server, whether folder names are same as your local?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found 2 problems with your code:

1. Import path is case sensitive(for some environments). And you are using '**C**omponents' instead of '**c**omponents'
2. Import of 'App' in index.js is wrong. Use following

   ```
   import App from './App';
   ```

Comment: It's just a favicon error now , I've seen those a million times.

Comment: Weird. I hate saying this but now its crashing at favicon and even though i can literally see the favicon in the browser it wont play

Comment: Yeah , funny thing was I had a rails app with this issue (that was fixed) but I can't seem to figure out how to translate that to react.

Comment: I removed the heroku procfile because i got some error relating with Bin www but of course nowheroku uploads a blank app.

Comment: can confirm this issue, this is my error  
`./src/App.js
remote:        Cannot find file './containers/UserPage' in './src'.`
my export name is Userpage,
when i change the file from UserPage to Userpage, fixed the issue and app deployed successfuly

Answer (score 10):

Thank you @Jason for asking this question and @Rakesh for answering.

I deployed **create-react-app** project on Heroku then I encountered a similar error where failed to build my project. the error was **routes.js** failed to import **signup.js**

> Heroku log

```
-----> Node.js app detected
       
-----> Creating runtime environment
       
       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=false
       NODE_VERBOSE=false
       
-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  10.16.3
       engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
       
       Resolving node version 10.16.3...
       Downloading and installing node 10.16.3...
       Using default npm version: 6.9.0
       
-----> Restoring cache
       Caching has been disabled because NODE_MODULES_CACHE=false
       
-----> Installing dependencies
       Installing node modules (package.json + package-lock)
       
       > core-js@2.6.9 postinstall /tmp/build_5d506b6dfc93b7f4b6575e02cc682130/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js
       > node scripts/postinstall || echo "ignore"
       
       
       > core-js@3.2.1 postinstall /tmp/build_5d506b6dfc93b7f4b6575e02cc682130/node_modules/core-js
       > node scripts/postinstall || echo "ignore"
       
       added 1507 packages from 719 contributors and audited 905071 packages in 35.746s
       found 0 vulnerabilities
       
       
-----> Build
       Running build
       
       > chat-app@0.1.0 build /tmp/build_5d506b6dfc93b7f4b6575e02cc682130
       > react-scripts build
       
       Creating an optimized production build...
       Failed to compile.
       
       ./src/routes.js                                         // my beautiful error here
       Cannot find file './Components/User/signup/signup.js' in './src'.   
       
       
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! chat-app@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the chat-app@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.ynm0W/_logs/2019-09-30T15_24_32_571Z-debug.log
-----> Build failed
       
       We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
       
       If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
       https://help.heroku.com/
       
       Love,
       Heroku
       
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
 !     Push failed
```

### solution

Heroku deploy projects on Linux servers, it means it is case sensitive if you make mistake the build will fail. I advise sticking with lowercase when naming files and directories.

```
my project structure

|root
|src
|  componets
|     user
|       signup
|routes
|index.js
```

## Alternatively,

After I correct mistakes, I still had the same error. so why?
I did not notice Git does not push the change. When you only rename the directory and even if you do **git add**, **git commit** and **git push** Git sometimes does not consider the changes. I advise after change go to the website to verify.

## Lastly,

when deploying to Heroku please deploy only the base branch. for Example **Master** or **develop**. I realized every time I deployed my feature branch, Heroku automatic detect my base branch which was **develop**.

Comment: Man you are life saver! I just spent 30 minutes figuring out what's happening

Comment: This also saved me hours more of tearing (what's left of) my hair out!! Thanks! I had no idea that Git didn't update case-changes in file names!

Answer (score 2):

In my case i renamed my file locally but when i pushed it on github it didn't reflected there. so i deleted that file and made new file with same content and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the suggestions above but none are working for me. Eventually, what I did was deleting the file that was complaining missing by heroku, and replaced it with a dummy component. After that, checked in my changes to heroku. Everything should be deployed successfully now.

Finally, I can swapped back my old dummy component with my original component and checked into heroku again and hallelujah, it worked !!!!

Hopefully that my workaround could save someone time :)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This problem on Heroku is usually due to the fact that you renamed a component, like for example MyComponent into Mycomponent, and both git cache and heroku build cache may give that problem. The solution is this: [Failed to compile: Cannot find file './containers/App/App' in './src'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55754231/failed-to-compile-cannot-find-file-containers-app-app-in-src) and clean the heroku build cache to to be safe:
https://help.heroku.com/18PI5RSY/how-do-i-clear-the-build-cache