# Failed to compile: Cannot find file './containers/App/App' in './src'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, heroku, build

I have been having a hard time pushing a React.js app to Heroku because I keep getting a failed to build message with the following amplifying information.

Heroku Build Console:

```
-----> Build
       Running build

       > veterinfo@0.1.0 build /tmp/build_2456efea678b82d24203cb2e2c7bcbd5
       > react-scripts build

       Creating an optimized production build...
       Failed to compile.

       ./src/index.js
       Cannot find file './containers/App/App' in './src'.
```

My index.js file:

```
import App from './containers/App/App'
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker'
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import rootReducer from './reducers'
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'

const store = createStore(rootReducer, composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunk)))

const router = (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <App />
        </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
)
```

File Structure:

```
src
  -->containers
    -->App
      -->__snapshots__
      -->App.js
      -->App.scss
      -->App.test.js
  -->index.js
```

I have tried deleting node_modules and reinstalling them,
I have tried clearing the build cache in heroku,
I have tried specifying `App.js` in the relative path,
I have tried specifying the node version in the yml and package.json files,
The Build passes locally with `npm run build`,
I have tried just passing in each component into the router's position and I have found that all of the components work but all of the containers do not (could this be a redux issue somehow?)

I am about out of ideas :/

Comment: Try reducing your code to the bare minimum and display simply a test component within index.js. If this doesn't work, it might be the configuration of your application. If it does work, then add components back in, one by one, and you will soon discover what the issue was

Comment: Thank you I'll give it a shot!

Comment: './components' work but './containers' do not :/

Answer (score 36):

You can start by clearing the cache and see if there are any files that have been renamed.

This will cache the entire directory:

```
git rm -r --cached .
```

Also, you have to add, commit and push the changes:

```
git add .
git commit -am 'Removing cached files'
```

Comment: This was exactly my problem. I renamed a file and apparently git didn't register that I renamed it. Removing the cache worked. +1

Comment: 10000 thanks! This was my issue, it was driving me crazy! Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Rename `containers` to `Containers` and `components` to `Components`

Comment: so whats the reason why this renaming is required?

Comment: Have no idea. This worked for me and perhaps for some other people.

Answer (score 3):

You might have changed the casing of the file names after you have commited to git. You can fix it by calling `git mv path/app.js path/App.js`. This explicitly changes the file name in git.

Comment: This was my exact problem. Somehow I was able to rename a few files without git tracking the name changes, but it was never an issue until deployment. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was fixed when I renamed the directory to `Containers` and the relative path to `import App from './Containers/App/App'`

Answer (score 0):

Check .gitignore , may be your files are not being sent to remote repository