# Heroku cannot find my file on deployment but it works locally

Tags: git, heroku, npm, heroku-cli

When I try to deploy to Heroku using `git push heroku master`  I get this error: `! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined) error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/afternoon-inlet-19669.git'`

I found this other [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54086013/cannot-find-file-on-trying-to-deploy-to-heroku-works-locally), and it helped me get rid of one of my first errors. Apparently GitHub doesn't update case-changes in file names on commit. So, I realized that I had a file named spinner.js which was actually named Spinner.js on my local machine.

But now, I am getting the error again.

```
-----> Node.js app detected
       
-----> Creating runtime environment
       
       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
       NODE_VERBOSE=false
       
-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  12.x
       engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
       
       Resolving node version 12.x...
       Downloading and installing node 12.18.0...
       Using default npm version: 6.14.4
       
-----> Installing dependencies
       Installing node modules (package.json + package-lock)
       
       > nodemon@2.0.4 postinstall /tmp/build_94cb6f8d6d9567ec2a8f7d9ac35a0f48/node_modules/nodemon
       > node bin/postinstall || exit 0
       
       Love nodemon? You can now support the project via the open collective:
        > https://opencollective.com/nodemon/donate
       
       added 370 packages from 220 contributors and audited 371 packages in 12.257s
       
       12 packages are looking for funding
         run `npm fund` for details
       
       found 1 low severity vulnerability
         run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
       
-----> Build
       Running heroku-postbuild
       
       > devconnector@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild /tmp/build_94cb6f8d6d9567ec2a8f7d9ac35a0f48
       > NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client
       
       
       > core-js@2.6.11 postinstall /tmp/build_94cb6f8d6d9567ec2a8f7d9ac35a0f48/client/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js
       > node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
       
       
       > core-js@3.6.5 postinstall /tmp/build_94cb6f8d6d9567ec2a8f7d9ac35a0f48/client/node_modules/core-js
       > node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
       
       
       > core-js-pure@3.6.5 postinstall /tmp/build_94cb6f8d6d9567ec2a8f7d9ac35a0f48/client/node_modules/core-js-pure
       > node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
       
       added 1686 packages from 803 contributors and audited 1690 packages in 41.105s
       
       59 packages are looking for funding
         run `npm fund` for details
       
       found 1 low severity vulnerability
         run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
       
       > client@0.1.0 build /tmp/build_94cb6f8d6d9567ec2a8f7d9ac35a0f48/client
       > react-scripts build
       
       Creating an optimized production build...
       Failed to compile.
       
       ./src/components/dashboard/Dashboard.js
       Cannot find file '../layout/Spinner' in './src/components/dashboard'.
       
       
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! client@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the client@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.BfgW5/_logs/2020-06-17T17_40_23_134Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! devconnector@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild: `NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the devconnector@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.BfgW5/_logs/2020-06-17T17_40_23_146Z-debug.log
-----> Build failed
       
       We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
       
       If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
       https://help.heroku.com/
       
       Love,
       Heroku
       
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
 !     Push failed
```

This is a link to my project on GitHub, any idea why Heroku is refusing to push the app? [My Project Link](https://github.com/codypafford/DevConnector/tree/master/client/src/components/layout)

### Edit

I believe the solution would be to get Github to realize that my file names have changed, it must still think the file is named spinner.js.

Comment: Check the `.gitignore` file in your project directory and see if that `Spinner` is kept to ignore

Comment: Nope, I checked, and it is not in the .gitignore file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> UPDATE: 01/22/2021

You can clear the build cache for an app using the following commands:

```
$ heroku plugins:install heroku-builds
$ heroku builds:cache:purge -a appname
```

The cache will be rebuilt on the next deploy. If you do not have any new code to deploy, you can push an empty commit.

```
$ git commit --allow-empty -m "Purge cache"
$ git push heroku master
```

Where appname is replaced by the name of the app you want to clear the cache for.

> OLD ANSWER for previous versions

You should clean your Heroku cache:

```
heroku repo:purge_cache -a your_app_name
```

then try again.

Comment: When I run the command, it produces a lot in the terminal and then says this `curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
`

Comment: Did you login first in your console `heroku login`?

Comment: I just tried it again and it worked so I think your solution did it. Thanks!!

Comment: check you have the right name of your app in heroku `heroku apps` this command will show you the list of apps under your user

Comment: I got a warning message like ``repo:purge_cache is not a heroku command.`` But got a solution from this link. https://help.heroku.com/18PI5RSY/how-do-i-clear-the-build-cache

Comment: Thanks, @Zin Minn I just update my answer, looks like Heroku changes the way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem that took my 100 hours to figure out. Turns out I had added a mandatory file's name to .gitignore....

So one single file wasn't uploading to neither Github, nor Heroku.
Heroku wouldn't tell me which file was missing, but DigitalOcean will tell you exactly which file is missing if you try to upload the app there.
Just Check your .gitignore file and just don't block anything other than node modules. Don't even block the package-lock.json files from being uploaded.

If this isn't the problem then it might be something with case sensitivity where a file name or component name compared to the import name isn't the same case for every letter. Probably the .gitignore thing though.